# VS 2017 Import Element

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and currently in my `.csproj` I have an `ImportElement` as follows:

```
<Import Project="$(Config)" />
```

where `Config` is a `.props` file.  Unfortunately, it seems as though VS 2017 cannot correctly load the project when this line exists in the `.csproj` file.  When right clicking on my project in VS and navigating to Properties, most of the panels are grayed out, and the Application panel complains that:

> An error occurred trying to load the page. Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

Is there an alternative way to import this `.props` file, or is there a known fix for this issue?

Comment: Can you include an example of the contents of your .props file?

Comment: I can, but I believe it's really only this one line.  Without it, VS 2017 loads the project fine.  With it, VS 2017 fails to properly load the project.

Comment: I'm wondering if the props file the same format/structure as your csproj file (or if you might have thought it could import a different type of file)... if that's not it, it's possible that a special property value is being set that causing problems elsewhere in the project system--either way, seeing a copy of your file would be very helpful in narrowing that down.

Comment: So are `Import` statements okay to use in VS 2017 projects?  I wasn't sure if they were deprecated in favor of something else.  Also, good idea, I'll take a look at the `.props` file.

Comment: Just had another thought, so try this as well:  replace "$(Config)" with the actual filename of your props file (no variable usage) and see if the project opens correctly.  If it works, the problem is with the value of the variable at the time of the import.  If it still fails with the same error, then yeah, is something inside that file.

Comment: Yes, ".csproj" still supports <import>.

Comment: Did you solved your issue @sir_thursday?

Comment: I am facing the same issue even without a props file